# Why does sbt exit while executing tests with no errors?

Tags: sbt

I've been using SBT to run unit tests on my code, and made some changes recently that have caused the tests to start acting weird.

None of the tests that I have seen fail, but when running the tests with sbt, it just stops in the middle and closes without giving an error message. There are no failed tests in the output.

Does anyone know why this might happen, or how I could figure out what the problem is?

Comment: Unless you configured sbt to run your tests forked they will run in the same JVM as sbt, so if they cause the JVM to crash or just call System.exit(0) it will terminate sbt as well as the test. Maybe configure the tests to fork and se what happens with that JVM?

Comment: That helped. Turns out there is a java.io.EOFException happening somehow.

Comment: @mp94 Could you answer your question and accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [the comment by @johanandren](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26060861/sbt-exits-while-running-tests-without-error#comment40829168_26060861), I managed to nail it down to an exception that was being thrown by forcing sbt to fork the tests in a new process. The exception was a `java.io.EOFException` disguised as an sbt out of memory error -- `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` -- and increasing it using the `-XX:MaxPermSize` argument in the `SBT_OPTS` environment variable as described in [SBT runs out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640823/sbt-runs-out-of-memory) helped fix that issue.