# SBT out of memory with subprojects

Tags: scala, sbt, out-of-memory

We're using SBT 0.13 and a Java 8 JVM on CircleCI to build a Play application with several subprojects. We were occasionally getting out of memory issues on CircleCI, where it aborted our build because it exceeded 4 GB of memory usage.

Yesterday, I added a new subproject to our build, and almost all builds fail now on the out of memory issue. It looks like adding subprojects also adds to the amount of memory used for our build.

I've tried several things to reduce our memory load:

- Add `_JAVA_OPTIONS: "-Xms512m -Xmx2048"` to `circle.yml` as described on [CircleCI's documentation pages](https://circleci.com/docs/oom/). (I noticed from the log that the JVM does pick up on this setting.)
- Add a `-mem` parameter to the SBT call.
- Add `concurrentRestrictions in Global += Tags.limit(Tags.Test, 1)` to the top of the SBT file, to make sure that at least the memory isn't used all at once.

All of these measures seemed to have helped, but I haven't found the definitive solution to this problem yet.

What else can I do to keep SBT's memory usage under control?

**EDIT**: Our project has 5 subprojects, with about 14000 lines of Scala code (and also, 21000 lines of Java code that we 'inherited'). The out-of-memory usually (but not always) occurs while executing static analysis using FindBugs: we use that in conjunction with the FindSecurityBugs plugin to find security issues.

Comment: how big is your project? how many lines of code do you have? when do you get OOM on compilation? packaging? tests phase?

Comment: @rumoku Good questions; I've edited my question to answer them.

Comment: You're seeing problems in a different phase than in this other question, but it may help you nonetheless: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640823/sbt-runs-out-of-memory?rq=1

Comment: @2rs2ts Thanks for the tip. However, we're using a Java 8 JVM so changing the PermGen settings won't help us. And forking out extra JVMs will help with PermGen issues for individual JVMs but not for collective memory usage in multiple JVMs, I'm afraid.

Comment: From my experience, in OOM cases you just keep increasing '-mem' size until it works. We have a big build (~20 projects) with lots of custom tasks for code analysis, etc., and '-mem 4096' usually works, but if not, then '-mem 8192' definitely helps.

Comment: The problem isn't that SBT runs out of memory. The problem is that CircleCI kills all processes once they take too much. Too much, in this case, is 4GB. `-mem 8196` is twice that...

Comment: Is that a PermGen problem? What java version are you on?

Comment: @Edmondo1984 Nope, it's a Java 8 JVM. Good point though; I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There two concerns here that are getting mixed:

1. Circle CI not picking up values for memory limits
2. SBT using an excessive amount of memory

The first issue has to be addressed looking at CircleCI documentation / examples. To investigate why you use so much memory, you can run your sbt locally with memory limits lower than the 4g (i.e. 2g). You will find yourself in one of these two cases:

1. Your tests are really using too much memory, maybe because of memory leaks. Your JVM exits because of an `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`. You should run the build locally with a profiler and see what's causing you problem (database connections not closed?)
2. Your tests are using too much memory due to SBT ability to re-load classes dynamically: in SBT is it possible to re-load class completely inside the same JVM (i.e. for example you can launch console, load the class, edit the file, recompile and relaunch console and re-load the class). As described in the Oracle documentation here, there is no limit for the `Maximum MetaSpace` in Java 8 and you should set one so that your heap + metaspace < 4gb. See https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/entry/about_g1_garbage_collector_permanent

Comment: 1. I have done all the things I listed in the question locally as well. I've limited everything to 1,5G, but every time I see the memory go as high as 2,5G. I did a poor man's profiling using `top` in a terminal, even though I know that's not the right way to do it. 2. I didn't know about this metaspace thing. I'll definitely try that out! Although I'm simply running `sbt test` and leaving the files alone while it runs.

Comment: The JVM occupation is not just heap but it includes MetaSpace too. Do your tests succeed by limiting memory to 2g heap?

Comment: I haven't tried to explicitly set the metaspace yet (although, from what I understand, SBT's `-mem` switch should take care of that). I'll try to set `-XX:MetaspaceSize` later today and report back.

Comment: The `MetaspaceSize` setting didn't exactly solve the problem, but your comments prodded me in the right direction. It turns out my settings actually did limit SBT's memory usage, except in `top` it shows as using more. So if I cap at 2048M, `top` will show 2500M or more. If I cap at 1024M, `top` will go up to slightly over 1700M. (In both cases I had the metaspace at 512M.) I don't quite understand it yet, but I'll take it. I'll give you the bounty, since you nudged me into trying a few new things that helped.

Comment: now you should attach a profiler such as jrockit to understand what's using so much memory

Comment: Indeed. I'll leave that exercise for when I come back from vacation, though. (I did only enough research to see if I could award the bounty, because it would expire otherwise :).)